# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user: CREATE VIEW USING JDBC in Databricks

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to create a view in Databricks by querying a table in my SQL Server database using JDBC.

The following `PySpark` code for creating a temporary view works without a problem,

```
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};database={2}".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase)
connectionProperties = {
  "user" : jdbcUsername,
  "password" : jdbcPassword,
  "driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
}

table_name = '<my_table>'
pushdown_query = f"(select * from {table_name}) AS tmp"
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=pushdown_query, properties=connectionProperties)
df.createOrReplaceTempView('tmp')
```

However, as soon as I try to bring this to Spark SQL code, I get the above error,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW tmp
USING JDBC
OPTIONS (
  url "<jdbc_url>",
  dbtable "(select * from <my_table>) AS tmp",
  user '<user>',
  password '<password>',
  driver "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
)
```

What is the problem here? The URL, credentials etc. that I am using here is the same as what has been used in the PySpark code.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use table, not view. Your PySpark code isn't really a 1:1 match to what you're trying to do in SQL. If you check documentation for [CREATE VIEW](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-view.html), you will see that it only could be created as query from another table/view.

Corresponding [CREATE TABLE](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-using.html) statement should look as following:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE jdbc_source
USING JDBC
OPTIONS (
  url "<jdbc_url>",
  dbtable "<my_table>",
  user '<user>',
  password '<password>',
  driver "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
)
```

Theoretically, `CREATE VIEW` may work as well, but you'll need to put all options into JDBC URL:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW tmp
AS SELECT * FROM jdbc.`<full-jdbc-url>`
```

Comment: could you please tell me what the format of the `<full-jdbc-url>` is?

Comment: it was pointed by @SaiVamsi

Comment: I get the following error when I try to query it this way,
java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI

Comment: something wrong with the syntax then

Comment: What syntax? I used the JDBC URL as given in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with **@Alex Ott**. But in your case, I could able to achieve your requirement by replacing `VIEW tmp` to  `TEMPORARY VIEW tmp`.

**Follow below syntax:**

```
%sql

CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW <view_name>
USING JDBC
OPTIONS (
  url "jdbc:sqlserver://<server_name>.database.windows.net:1433;database<database_name>;user=<user_name>;password=<Password>;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;",
  dbtable "(select * from sample_table1) AS tmp",
  driver "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
)
```

**My Execution:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I am still getting the same error with this query as well. My password contains '@' and '$' characters. Could this have something to do with it?

Comment: Hi @Minura Punchihewa, even though my password contains '@' it's working fine. can you provide a full error message or snippet?